# Unable to find config file when generating test

Tags: php, codeception

I'm using the absolute path to my yml file... is that not the correct file I should be providing a path for?  I've verified that the path I'm using is correct...

```
$ vendor/bin/codecept generate:cept -config="~/path/to/codeception.yml" acceptance createUser

  [Codeception\Exception\Configuration]  
  Configuration file could not be found  

generate:cept [-c|--config[="..."]] suite test
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was, I must've corrupted something. but rebuilding my codeception setup using `vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap` resolved the issue.